# How to avoid overlapping date ranges when using a grouping clause?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a situation where I need to find time spans between value changes.  I tried a simple group by clause but it eliminates overlapping changes.  Consider the following example:

```
create table #items (
      code varchar(4)
    , class varchar(4)
    , txdate datetime
)

insert into #items (code, class, txdate) values ('A', 'C', '2010-01-01');
insert into #items (code, class, txdate) values ('A', 'C', '2010-01-02');
insert into #items (code, class, txdate) values ('A', 'C', '2010-01-03');
insert into #items (code, class, txdate) values ('A', 'D', '2010-01-04');
insert into #items (code, class, txdate) values ('A', 'D', '2010-01-05');
insert into #items (code, class, txdate) values ('A', 'C', '2010-01-06');
insert into #items (code, class, txdate) values ('A', 'C', '2010-01-07');
insert into #items (code, class, txdate) values ('A', 'D', '2010-01-08');
insert into #items (code, class, txdate) values ('A', 'D', '2010-01-09');

select code
, class
, min(txdate) mindate
, max(txdate) maxdate
from #items
group by code, class
```

This returns the following results (notice the overlapping date ranges):

```
|code|class|mindate   |maxdate   |
----------------------------------
|A   |C    |2010-01-01|2010-01-07|
|A   |D    |2010-01-04|2010-01-09|
```

I would like to have the query return the following:

```
|code|class|mindate   |maxdate   |
----------------------------------
|A   |C    |2010-01-01|2010-01-03|
|A   |D    |2010-01-04|2010-01-05|
|A   |C    |2010-01-06|2010-01-07|
|A   |D    |2010-01-08|2010-01-09|
```

Any ideas and suggestions?

Comment: Your input dates all have January for the month, yet some of your results have April. Have you transposed months and days in your results when putting them on here?

Comment: @CanSpice: My dates are using yyyy-mm-dd format.  I caught the error and corrected it.  Thx

Comment: Okay, then your example needs to include the dates in April, because all you're entering is dates in January, yet your example returns dates in April.

Comment: +1 for giving table definition, sample data, your best try, and expected results! Try using google: `sql server islands`, however your given table may not be ideal for ANY solution.  Any solution will require that you can order you data in sequence properly.  I'm not sure how you can do that with your three columns.  possibly txdate is unique? or you have an identity column you did not list?

Comment: @KM: Thanks for the comments.  If you have a solution that would work with an identity column, please feel free to share a modified version of the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching `SQL SERVER ISLANDS` as suggested by @KM, I came up with the following query which seems to work well when additional class codes are added to the dataset.

```
select a.code, a.class, a.txdate as mindate, b.txdate as maxdate
from (
    --Find minimum island
    select code
        , class
        , txdate
        , row_number() over (order by code, class, txdate) as n
    from #items tb1
    where not exists (
        select *
        from #items tb2
        where datediff(d, tb1.txdate, tb2.txdate) = -1      
          and tb1.class = tb2.class
          and tb1.code = tb2.code
    ) 
) as a
inner join (
    --Find maximum island 
    select code
        , class
        , txdate
        , row_number() over (order by code, class, txdate) as n
    from #items tb1
    where not exists (
        select *
        from #items tb2
        where datediff(d, tb1.txdate, tb2.txdate) = 1   
          and tb1.class = tb2.class
          and tb1.code = tb2.code
    ) 
) as b on a.n = b.n
```

The only caveat to this approach is that the number of entries in the minimum set needs to match the number of entries in the maximum set.  So far I have not been able to do anything that would make this not true.  However, I did not test null values or performance.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: As pointed out in the comments, this is still not quite right.

```
;with cteNtile as (
    select code, class, txdate, 
           ntile((select count(*) from (select NULL as dummy from #items group by code, class) a)) over(partition by code, class order by txdate) as tilenum
        from #items
)
select code, class, MIN(txdate) as mindate, MAX(txdate) as maxdate
    from cteNtile
    group by code, class, tilenum
    order by mindate, maxdate
```

Comment: +1: it returns the correct output.  Anyway to do this without the intial record count?

Comment: @k rey: Not that I've been able to come up with yet.

Comment: +1, you can drop the local variable and just use: `ntile((select count(*) from (select NULL as dummy from @items group by code, class) a))`

Comment: This solution works greats for the given data, but doesn't look like a generic one. What if there is an additional class code A, E. Wouldn't it mess up the output?

Comment: @XtremeBytes: I agree. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @XtremeBytes: yes, you are right, the output changes with an additional class code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the query that can give you the desired result.

```
;WITH items1 AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY txdate) rowid, code, class, txdate
from #items
),
items2 AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowid) id, rowid, i1.Code, i1.Class, i1.txdate
FROM items1 i1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM items1 i2
                  WHERE i2.txdate < i1.txdate
                  AND i2.class = i1.class
                  AND i2.Code = i1.Code 
                  AND i2.rowid+1=i1.rowid)
)
SELECT items2.code, items2.class, items2.txdate mindate, items1.txdate maxdate
FROM items2,  items2 items3, items1 
WHERE (items2.id+1=items3.id AND items3.rowid-1=items1.rowid)
OR items2.rowid = (SELECT MAX(t.rowid) FROM items1 t)
UNION 
SELECT items2.code, items2.class, MAX(items2.txdate) mindate, MAX(items1.txdate) maxdate
FROM items2, items1 
WHERE items1.class = items2.class
GROUP BY items1.class, items2.class, items2.code, items2.class
ORDER BY items2.txdate
```

Comment: +1: This works with the result set given.  However, adding an additional class code combination messes up the output.

Comment: @k rey: ok.. I got the reason. It was not working for data like (Code: B and Class: D). I had missed one comparison between Codes. I have modified my query accordingly. Let me know if it works for you now..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can´t do this with a simple select statement.

You can use a cursor to iterate over the rows and identify the "class" changes.