# Find the start and end date (set based) in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have the below.

```
Name    Date
A   2011-01-01 01:00:00.000
A   2011-02-01 02:00:00.000
A   2011-03-01 03:00:00.000
B   2011-04-01 04:00:00.000
A   2011-05-01 07:00:00.000
```

The desired output is

```
Name       StartDate                        EndDate
-------------------------------------------------------------------
A          2011-01-01 01:00:00.000         2011-04-01 04:00:00.000    
B          2011-04-01 04:00:00.000         2011-05-01 07:00:00.000    
A          2011-05-01 07:00:00.000         NULL
```

How to achieve the same using TSQL in a set based approach.

[DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language) is as under

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(PersonName VARCHAR(32), [Date] DATETIME) 
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('A', '2011-01-01 01:00:00') 
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('A', '2011-01-02 02:00:00') 
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('A', '2011-01-03 03:00:00') 
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('B', '2011-01-04 04:00:00') 
INSERT INTO @t VALUES('A', '2011-01-05 07:00:00')

Select * from @t
```

Comment: I don't understand how you are figuring the desired output. How do you decide what the end date is? For example, in the desired output you have a record:
   name  start date                end date    
    A    2011-01-01 01:00:00.000   2011-04-01 04:00:00.000  

But the input had that date 2011-04-01 04:00:00.000 associated with name B. How do we determine what the end date should be for a record. What is the definition of a record?

Comment: The end date of a record is the start date of another record. So A's startd date is 2011-01-01 01:00:00.000  but B's is 2011-04-01 04:00:00.000. So A's end date is 2011-04-01 04:00:00.000. Similarly The A that is following B, is having a start date as 2011-05-01 07:00:00.000 which is the end date for B.

Comment: But how do you know which record to choose as the end date of a particular record?

Comment: The first diffrence found in the Name. i.e.e A is appearing 3 times in the beginning and then B came on the 4th row. So 1 transaction is over. On the 5th row again A came. So from 4th to 5th there is a new transaction

Comment: Unfortunately, without some sort of logic for determining how you are choosing end dates and consolidating the data into the output, I don't think there is any way anyone can help write the SQL to get the output your desiring. There has to be some sort of logic to follow to get from A (the input) to B (the output).

Comment: Ok, I see, but even so, then it would seem the output for that record should have an end date of 2011-03-01 03:00:00.000, not 2011-04-01 04:00:00.000.

Comment: The LEAD or LAG functions would help, if they were supported.  But the primary problem is the partitioning is based on the `personname` value...

Comment: Similar post [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620066/how-to-avoid-overlapping-date-ranges-when-using-a-grouping-clause/4622591#4622591) can give you good approach.

Comment: Possibly related: [answer to "How to avoid overlapping date ranges when using a grouping clause?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620066/how-to-avoid-overlapping-date-ranges-when-using-a-grouping-clause/4622591#4622591)

Answer (score 8):

```
;WITH cte1
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) -
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonName
                ORDER BY Date) AS G
         FROM   @t),
     cte2
     AS (SELECT PersonName,
                MIN([Date]) StartDate,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  MIN([Date])) AS rn
         FROM   cte1
         GROUP  BY PersonName,
                   G)
SELECT a.PersonName,
       a.StartDate,
       b.StartDate AS EndDate
FROM   cte2 a
       LEFT JOIN cte2 b
         ON a.rn + 1 = b.rn
```

Because the result of CTEs are not generally materialised however 
you may well find you get better performance if you materialize the 
intermediate result yourself as below.

```
DECLARE @t2 TABLE (
  rn         INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  PersonName VARCHAR(32),
  StartDate  DATETIME );

INSERT INTO @t2
SELECT PersonName,
       MIN([Date]) StartDate
FROM   (SELECT *,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) -
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonName
               ORDER BY Date) AS G
        FROM   @t) t
GROUP  BY PersonName,
          G
ORDER  BY StartDate

SELECT a.PersonName,
       a.StartDate,
       b.StartDate AS EndDate
FROM   @t2 a
       LEFT JOIN @t2 b
         ON a.rn + 1 = b.rn
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  PersonName,
  StartDate = MIN(Date),
  EndDate
FROM (
  SELECT
    PersonName,
    Date,
    EndDate = (
      /* get the earliest date after current date
         associated with a different person */
      SELECT MIN(t1.Date)
      FROM @t AS t1
      WHERE t1.Date > t.Date
        AND t1.PersonName <> t.PersonName
    )
  FROM @t AS t
) s
GROUP BY PersonName, EndDate
ORDER BY 2
```

Basically, for every `Date` we find the nearest date after it such that is associated with a different `PersonName`. That gives us `EndDate`, which now distinguishes for us consecutive groups of dates for the same person.

Now we only need to group the data by `PersonName` & `EndDate` and get the minimal `Date` in every group as `StartDate`. And yes, sort the data by `StartDate`, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer with the cte is a good one. Another option would be to iterate over the collection in any case. It's not set based, but it is another way to do it.

You will need to iterate to either A. assign a unique id to each record that corresponds to its transaction, or B. to actually get your output.

TSQL is not ideal for iterating over records, especially if you have a lot, and so I would recommend some other way of doing it, a small .net program or something that is better at iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Get a row number so you will know where the previous record is. Then, take a record and the next record after it. When the state changes we have a candidate row.

```
select 
  state, 
  min(start_timestamp),
  max(end_timestamp)

from
(
    select
        first.state, 
        first.timestamp_ as start_timestamp,
        second.timestamp_ as end_timestamp

        from
        (
            select
                *, row_number() over (order by timestamp_) as id
            from test
        ) as first

        left outer join
        (
            select
                *, row_number() over (order by timestamp_) as id
            from test
        ) as second
        on 
            first.id = second.id - 1 
            and first.state != second.state
) as agg
group by state
    having max(end_timestamp) is not null 

union

-- last row wont have a ending row
--(select state, timestamp_, null from test order by timestamp_ desc limit 1)
    -- I think it something like this for sql server
     (select top state, timestamp_, null from test order by timestamp_ desc)

order by 2
;
```

Tested with PostgreSQL but should work with SQL Server as well

Answer (score 0):

There's a very quick way to do this using a bit of Gaps and Islands theory:

```
WITH CTE as (SELECT PersonName, [Date]
                   , Row_Number() over (ORDER BY [Date])
                     - Row_Number() over (ORDER BY PersonName, [Date]) as Island
             FROM @t)

Select PersonName, Min([Date]), Max([Date])
from CTE
GROUP BY Island, PersonName
ORDER BY Min([Date])
```